# Luasocket Telnet Check

Tags: lua, luasocket

I'd like to write a Lua script to run in the background of my server that checks a connection to a server and port every few minutes.

Basically, the logic would go as such:

```
local success = check_connection("avalon-rpg.com", 443)
if not success then
  os.execute([[kill $(ps aux | grep '[b]ouncer' | awk '{print $2}')]])
  os.execute([[./byoing.sh]])
end
```

I'm thinking Luasocket will be used to do this, but I'm not sure where to start. Could someone help me with this? It should be a fairly simple project. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `local res, err = require('socket').connect("avalon-rpg.com", 443)` to do this (you'll get `nil, "error message"` back if the connection can't be established).

See [connect](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/socket.html#connect) documentation for details.

Comment: This will do nicely. Thank you :)